# Facebook Realtime register "Invalid response" with Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time

I want to register a Facebook Realtime callback function using the Graph API Explorer. My function back-end is a Servlet and the function is invoked by Facebook passing all parameters as documented.

The Servlet returns the hub.challenge (a random String) as documented by Facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.0#subscribing

Sadly the Graph API Explorer has the output:

```
{
    "error": "Invalid response"
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Greetings, Tim Mickelson

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? Can you share the solution?

Comment: I'm using another strategy not Facebook Graph API Explorer and the issue is closed for me. Sorry about the late answer.